# Javascript image onload callback class-intern function

Tags: javascript, image, callback, onload

```
Objekt.prototype.loadImg = function(pImg){
    if(pImg!=null){
        this.imgLoaded=false;
        this.img = null;
        this.img = new Image();         
        this.img.src = pImg;     
        this.img.onload = function(){
            alert("!");
            this.autoSize();                
            this.imgLoaded=true;
        }; 

    }
}
```

My Problem is that "this" is invalid in the "onload = function()"-function!

alert("!"); is executed, but not the Objekt.prototype.autoSize()-function for example!

What do I have to do to call my "class-intern"-functions (e.g. autoSize) ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `onload` function isn't called with your objekt as receiver. So `this`, inside this callback, isn't the desired object.

You can do this to transmit `this` to the `onload` callback :

```
Objekt.prototype.loadImg = function(pImg){
    if(pImg!=null){
        this.imgLoaded=false;
        this.img = null;
        this.img = new Image();         
        this.img.src = pImg;     
        var _this = this;
        this.img.onload = function(){
            alert("!");
            _this.autoSize();                
            _this.imgLoaded=true;
        }; 
    }
}
```